# How do I validate the size of an Array?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write some code which reads a csv file and ensures that each row will have the same amount of elements within it. However, despite my csv file not having the same amount of elements within each rows, it keeps telling me I do. Can anybody help me, I'm very new to java to any help will be very appreciated

```
     private static boolean validateRectangle(int[][] myArray)
     {
         boolean valid = true;

         int rows = myArray.length;
         int columns = myArray[0].length;

         try
         {
             if (rows >= columns)
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
                 {
                     if (myArray[0].length == myArray[i].length)
                     {
                         valid = false;
                         System.out.println(myArray[i].length);
                     }

                 }

             }
             if (columns > rows)
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < myArray[0].length; i++)
                 {
                     if (myArray[0].length == myArray[i].length)
                     {
                         valid = false;
                         System.out.println(myArray[i].length);
                     }

                 }

             }

         }
         catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid, rows aren't equal");
         }

         System.out.println(valid);
         return valid;
     }
```

Comment: Compare the length of every row to the length of the first row. The number of rows has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Would you please explain your algorithm in the text box? You're not reading anything in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare like this:

```
    private static boolean validateRectangle(int[][] myArray) {
        if (myArray == null || myArray.length == 0) return false;
        int columnLength = myArray[0].length;
        for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (columnLength != myArray[i].length)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4} };
        System.out.println(validateRectangle(arr));

        int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} };
        System.out.println(validateRectangle(arr));
    }
```

, output

```
false
true
```

Comment: I tried to use this code but even this doesn't work, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Let me try to recap, do you want to verify each column's size with another column's size, right?

Comment: I just wanna make sure every column is the same size.

Comment: Okay, let me check that

Comment: I've got it working dude, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: you are welcome :), could you approve the answer :D